# My win32 emacs crashes randomly. How can I debug this?

Tags: debugging, emacs

My emacs configuration was somewhat unstable under Linux, and under Windows it is proving to be much worse.   It seems to crash randomly.  How can I debug what's going on?  What sort of configuration errors can make emacs lock up or hard crash?

By the way, I know about ESC-ESC-ESC and C-g.  The crashes are worse than that :-(

Comment: That should fix your problems: Alt+! vim ... sorry couldn't resist ;)

Comment: I've never even heard of emacs crashing, that's weird. When you say "my port to Windows"...did you actually port it yourself? Or using one of the standard Windows builds?

Comment: What type of crash?

If it is a segmentation fault (I doubt it) its a emacs bug. You can use gdb.

If not, its a elisp bug (surely your emacs config). You can use emacs elisp debugger.

Comment: My configuration was written while I was using Linux.  I had to do some finagling to get it to work in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bunch of problems with emacs on win32, when I upgraded to emacs v23.

Random spins, weird behavior, completely unusable.

It turned out to be due to a duplicate library - I had an old version of semantic package in my load path, and emacs 23 added in a new version of semantic. Somehow these two packages were fighting each other and causing all the spins.

The way I debugged or diagnosed it was to just eliminate everything from my .emacs, and stepwise add things back in.  Add one small stanza, then restart emacs.  If it worked, add another stanza, start emacs again.  When I speak of stanzas, it was things like `(require 'cc-mode)`.  I added and tested every "require" statement separately. I also treated the defun for a hook function, and the line that adds the hook fn into the appropriate hook, as a single stanza. When I added the line that changed the loadpath, the spin/hang came back and that led to the solution.

---

You used the words "my port"... I'm not sure what that means but if you are compiling emacs yourself, maybe consider NOT doing that.  The binary release of Emacs for Win32 works just fine for me.

Comment: Binary search should work just as well for this: comment out half of the config; if it breaks, uncomment it and recurse on the other half.  Otherwise recurse on that half.